# CoreBluetooth: How to Identify bluetooth devices like BlueScope app?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

In my centralManager, how can I go about identifying bluetooth devices like this Bluescope app.

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/bluescope/id1530096924

I see the [Bluetooth spec has a device info service](https://github.com/oesmith/gatt-xml/blob/master/org.bluetooth.service.device_information.xml) defined, but it only covers vendor / manufacturer info.

`org.bluetooth.service.device_information  "0x180A"`

I couldn't find any related info or APIs in [CoreBluetooth programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html) and Apple developer forums.

Any ideas how can I get the device information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suspect that they've compiled a large database to identify popular products. Much of what's displayed on that screen is not trivially available in a uniform way. In particular, note the icons (and especially the AppleTV icon). There's nothing in the common BLE services that will return a display icon for the device. They have some lookup table, and a bunch of icons of their own.

Also, strings like "MacBook Pro 13-inch 2020" are generally not advertised. Instead you get an identifier like "MacBookPro11,5" and you need [a table](https://github.com/devicekit/DeviceKit/blob/master/Source/Device.generated.swift) to work out what that means. ([Here's](https://github.com/SIXFLOW-OpenCore-KR/OpenCore-Desktop-Guide/blob/b21312584fd093db51e056cee09e2c132771d5a7/extras/smbios.md) another example table for MacBooks.)

I suggest trying [nRF Connect](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/nrf-connect-for-mobile/id1054362403) to see what the raw data looks like.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try using nRF connect.